# Can I force a function to live in the boot sector without overwriting the bootloader?

Tags: bootloader, flash

Not for any practical purpose but just out of curiosity, I want to abuse the flash memory and write it dynamically at run-time.  This is, in a sense, what the bootloader does.  If I understand it, the only way to modify flash is to do so from instructions written to the boot sector.  Is it possible to stick a simple function in there that writes to flash memory, and call it from running code?  If so, how do I put it there?  I have no issue with calling functions from function pointers, so I don't think I'll have an issue actually calling the function once I get there, but I need to know how to stick into flash in the first place.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Optiboot version 8 has a `do_spm` function which can be called from application. The Optiboot repository contains [an example](https://github.com/Optiboot/optiboot/tree/master/optiboot/examples/test_dospm) for the use of this function.

SPM is the AVR CPU instruction to write to flash memory. The Optiboot wraps this in a function. A pointer to this function is put in a 'vector table' at the beginning of the bootloader. The first pointer jumps to `main`, the second pointer jumps to `do_spm`. The optiboot.h then has the function as (version for small Optiboot)

```c
typedef void (*do_spm_t)(uint16_t address, uint8_t command, uint16_t data);
const do_spm_t do_spm = (do_spm_t)((FLASHEND-511+2)>>1)
```

I made an enhancement of this, a [copy_flash_pages function](https://github.com/Optiboot/optiboot/pull/269) with reset option to bootload an AVR from its own flash. It is added as third entry in the 'vectors table' of Optiboot. It is used in my [ArduinoOTA](https://github.com/jandrassy/ArduinoOTA) library for AVR MCUs.

```c
typedef void (*copy_flash_pages_t)(uint32_t dest, uint32_t src, uint16_t page_count, uint8_t reset);
const copy_flash_pages_t copy_flash_pages = (copy_flash_pages_t)((FLASHEND-1023+4)>>1);
```

Comment: That's very interesting, thanks.  I will check it out